# Android Studio, app se cierra al iniciar

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sqlite

hice un crud de agregar y consultar en android studio, pero cuando consulto la app se me cierra, veo mi código bien, ¿qué podría hacer?

```
public void consulta(View view){

        adminBD admin = new adminBD(this,"baseDatos", null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase baseDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();
        String nombreDeUsuario = etnombre.getText().toString();

        if(! nombreDeUsuario.isEmpty()){

            Cursor fila = baseDatos.rawQuery("select apellido, correo, contraseña from usuarios where nombre= "+ nombreDeUsuario, null);

            if (fila.moveToFirst()){
                apellido.setText(fila.getString(0));
                correo.setText(fila.getString(1));
                clave.setText(fila.getString(2));
                //baseDatos.close();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(this,"No existe un usuario con ese nombre", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            baseDatos.close();



        }
    }

// clase de la base de datos
public class adminBD extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public adminBD(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase baseDatos) {
        baseDatos.execSQL("create table usuarios(nombre text,apellido text, correo text, contraseña text)");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists usuarios");
        db.execSQL("create table usuarios(nombre text,apellido text, correo text, contraseña text)");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pueden ser muchas las causas, la mayor parte es por errores no controlados, donde deberías encontrar el error especifico o la pila de errores, esto en la pestaña 'Run' del IDE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O en la pestaña Debug si estas utilizando el método depuración pasa a paso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la consola aparecerá el error especifico y también la línea que disparo el error, así creas un nuevo hilo con ese detalle.